# Why four spaces turn into two when copying lines from gVim into LibreOffice?

Tags: indentation, office

I want to paste some codes in gVim:
[image]

You see that there are 4 blank spaces at the beginning of line 2 till line 4.

Issue `%y+` in gVim, copy all the lines into register, then paste it in LibreOffice:

[image]

The four white spaces turn into two.

How can I keep the previous format in gVim when to copy codes into LibreOffice?

Comment: Unfortunately, you posted a screenshot of your text so nobody here can see if you use tabs or spaces for indentation. My guess is the latter. And maybe libreoffice indents tabs as two spaces. Who knows? You could `:set list` to see for yourself. I'm voting to close, you need to provide more detail.

Comment: Updated as you expect ,adding the list setting.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Vim. All you need to do is use a monospace font in LibreOffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem is that the font you use in OpenOffice is not fixed width.

I suggest that you use you switch in LibreOffice to Lucida Console or Courrier to verify my hypothesis.

Remark: the with of space   is very different that the with of `w` on non fixed with.